# Redirect www.mainsite.com/subsite/wp-login to www.mainsite.com/wp-login

Tags: multisite

I'm using groupblog feature and hence multisite is required with it .

If a new user(not logged in) reaches any of the groupblog directly viz. a subsite and clicks the login button he's redirected to www.mainsite.com/subsite/wp-login.php whereas i want him to reach at www.mainsite.com/wp-login.php .
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `www.mainsite.com` is the main blog and `www.mainsite.com/subtitle` is a dynamic child blog. You can use MU api for this:

```
add_action("init", function(){
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'wp-login.php' !== $pagenow ) return;

    global $blog_id;

    $main_blog_ID = 1; // main site ID (use get_current_blog_id() to get ID)

    if ( (int) $blog_id !== (int) $main_blog_ID ) {
        switch_to_blog( $main_blog_ID );
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
        exit;
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Where do I paste this code ? I'm not too much of acquainted with wordpress development . Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: The code shall reside in your child theme's `functions.php` file, or in a custom plugin that is active all over the network. You are welcome. Please accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: Can you help me a bit more ::: As there are multiple blogs in my network so I want to add a follow button on each blog so that whenever someone posts something on his blog the followers get a notification sort of thing or they see the article in their news feed

Comment: Don't you think there are ready plugins for this purpose? e.g Jetpack, just search for `follow blog` and such keywords for plugins.. Because this will require more code and work

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this -- which is similar to the above option, but persists some options through and uses a better action and some more salient functions:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Multisite Login Consolidation
 * Author: georgestephanis
 * License: GPLv2+
 * Requires PHP: 7
 * Network: true
 */

add_action( 'login_init', function() {
    if ( ! is_multisite() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! is_main_site() ) {
        switch_to_blog( get_main_site_id() );
        wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ?? null ) );
        exit;
    }
} );
```

Here it is in a gist if that's easier to download the file off of.  It should be able to be installed and network activated pretty simply.

https://gist.github.com/georgestephanis/ffa8617e066a39fc80fa3d487535071b